# Ubuntu 13.04 boot problem. Devices are being listed

Tags: boot, nvidia, screen

After I installed nVidia driver whenever I start up Ubuntu 13.04 it stays approximately 1 minutes as image shown in link below.

[image]

Then it shows me a black screen,

[image]

When I press power button, closing screen is coming up and stays "Will now halt". What is the problem with it?

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it. Ctrl-F and search for Nvidia and you'll find some helpful tips.

Comment: I had a black screen too and solved it by removing quiet splash from boot altogether, though I don't have the same hardware as you so it might not be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, at boot select a recovery mode and then the root option (I don't have it in front of me to give you the exact wording).

Try uninstalling and reinstalling Nvidia driver: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia` then try reinstalling by `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates-dev` and then reboot.